# Type of voice/usage

Tags: passive-voice, british-english

The car impressed me, and handles a dream. **Isn't that unusual with these older models.** After some miles through the city, it was off to the countryside, where I could really take the car up a gear or two.

**Who doesn't just love speeding through the countryside, and not worrying about the speed cameras?** The gear shift, brakes and interior are top of the line, and **I didn't mention the leather seats did I**: they are sublime.

What would you class the distinction of voice in the bolded sentences, and you could perceive the first example as either speaking to the reader directly or representing a thought the writer was having: I guess there is no way of drawing a distinction with punctuation without putting: It made me think 'Isn't that unusual with these older models'.

Answer (score 1):

All three bolded sentences are couched as questions.  A question implies that there is someone within earshot, so to speak, that the speaker has a listener.

This is narrative artifice, of course.

Comment: I agree and add that the artifice continues outside the questions, where the tone is that of casual conversation.